# Child Components are not updating after store update

Tags: angular

When Items get updated with visible property as false, the items must hide. and when the visible property becomes true, the item must appear.

But no, when I change visible for some property to false,  The items are hiding, but when I change back to true, Items dont appear. But they are in Dom. 
What's the error in Code?

```
 // Parent.ts 


   export class Parent {
  items$: Observable<Item[]>;
  items: Item[];

this.items$ = this.store.select(state => state.items);
this.items$.subscribe(
  items => {
    if (items.length > 0) {
      this.items = items.filter(x => x.visible === true);

    }
  },
  error => {
    console.log('error', error);
  }
);
}


// Parent.html 

  < div * ngFor="let item of items" >
    <child[data]="item" > </child>
      < /div>

// child.ts 

export class child {
  @Input()
  data: Item;

  name: string;


  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private state: State<AppState>,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.name = this.data.name;
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // only run when property "data" changed
    console.log("called");
    if (changes['viewport']) {
      this.canvasId = 'canvas' + this.viewport.id;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with ngrx I try to stick with observables and the async pipe to update the UI.

Try

```
this.items$ = this.store.pipe(
    select(state => state.items),
    map(i => i.filter(x => x.visible)),
);
```

And in the html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">
```